# Laravel - Include table in mailable

Tags: css, laravel, email, html-table, html-email

I'm sending out a order confirmation and resumee... I'd need this table to be shown inside the email, but bootstrap is not working in the mail.blade file...

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row ">
    <div class="table-responsive w-100">
        <div class="d-table w-100">
            <div class="d-table-row">
                <div class="d-table-cell p-2 pl-5 pr-5 border border-dark text-center">Licence type</div>
                <div class="d-table-cell p-2 pl-5 pr-5 border border-dark text-center">Price</div>
                <div class="d-table-cell p-2 pl-5 pr-5 border border-dark text-center">Quantity</div>
                <div class="d-table-cell p-2 pl-5 pr-5 border border-dark text-center">Subtotal</div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-table-row">
                <div class="d-table-cell p-2 border border-dark text-center">100 Mb</div>
                <div class="d-table-cell p-2 border border-dark text-center">{{$lic100->price}} €</div>
                <div class="d-table-cell p-2 border border-dark text-center">{{$order->nr100}}</div>
                <div class="d-table-cell p-2 border border-dark text-center"><div id="subt100">{{ ($lic100->price * $order->nr100 ) }} €</div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-table-row">
                <div class="d-table-cell p-2 border border-dark text-center">250 Mb</div>
                <div class="d-table-cell p-2 border border-dark text-center">{{$lic250->price}} €</div>
                <div class="d-table-cell p-2 border border-dark text-center">{{$order->nr250}}</div>
                <div class="d-table-cell p-2 border border-dark text-center"><div id="subt250">{{ ($lic250->price * $order->nr250 ) }} €</div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-table-row">
                <div class="d-table-cell p-2 border border-dark text-center">500 Mb</div>
                <div class="d-table-cell p-2 border border-dark text-center">{{$lic500->price}} €</div>
                <div class="d-table-cell p-2 border border-dark text-center">{{$order->nr500}}</div>
                <div class="d-table-cell p-2 border border-dark text-center"><div id="subt500">{{ ($lic500->price * $order->nr500 ) }} €</div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-table-row">
                <div class="d-table-cell"></div>
                <div class="d-table-cell"></div>
                <div class="d-table-cell p-2 border border-dark text-center">Total:</div>
                <div class="d-table-cell p-2 border border-dark text-center"><div id="total">{{ ($lic100->price * $order->nr100 ) + ($lic250->price * $order->nr250 ) + ($lic500->price * $order->nr500 ) }} €</div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

how can I make this work properly? Do I have to convert it to a normal html `<table>`?

Comment: See here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#customizing-the-components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap won't work in an email environment because external stylesheets won't usually work. Furthermore, embedding it wouldn't even work because email clients can only accept certain tags.

You need to make this a table layout, or a table layout that looks like cards.

As you have a rather large table, you may consider using a card layout so that mobiles can handle the information nicely. A few examples including code are here: https://medium.com/@nathankeenmelb/responsive-datatables-through-card-ui-design-for-email-aca6f3c395a2